# Why can't we allow users to ask if their problem is solved or they have used a different pattern?

Tags: feature-request

I was wondering why we Stack Overflow users could always flag every answer which has these tags:

1. I am also stuck on this, did you solve this problem?
2. I am having the same problem, did you get a solution from different sources?

Can't we add this feature (ask if a problem was resolved or not), because many users do not delete their questions even after getting it resolved or they didn't answer itself on their question. With this feature (ask for problem resolved or not) we can also engage users to add an answer by themselves if it's resolved.

Comment: i don't believe there's anything stopping them from posting those as comments (though i could be mistaken), only that if they post it as an answer they'll be removed because they aren't answers

Comment: Generally, I judge if a question is solved or not by seeing if there is a selected answer or not. I really don't see the need for having a system like you describe. How would we judge if a question is solved? Would the OP have to explicitly state that their question was solved?

Comment: "because many users do not delete their questions even after getting it resolved" -- I'm not sure if I get this passage. No one is supposed to delete their questions (just) because they were solved. Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: What you're describing is one of the problems that Stack Overflow was created to *solve*. https://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 22):

> why can't we allow users to ask if their problem is solved or they have used a different pattern

How would you like it if you posted a question about a problem you've been stuck at for days or weeks and every single "answer" you got was nothing but

1. I am also stuck in this, did you solved this problem?
2. I am having same problem, did you get any solution from different sources.

and all you could tell them was "no, I did not solve it yet", because *no one* was giving you the solution?

I mean sure, you'd probably feel a little less alone, and maybe sympathize with them. But Stack Overflow is not about pity or sympathy. It's about getting answers to questions.

> can't we add this feature (ask for problem resolved or not) because many users do not delete their questions even after getting it resolved or they didn't answer itself on their question

That's why we'd much rather they refrained from saying anything in the first place. People just fire and forget in the hopes of maybe getting a reply, but if they don't, they never follow up. We're left to clean up their messes either way.

> with this feature (ask for problem resolved or not) we can also engage users to add answer by themselves if its resolved.

If you're just asking for a way for users to bookmark questions for future reference, that's built into both the browser, and the site (mark a question as favorite).